# Trying to run hello world on C and the output throwing this error on Mac on VS : zsh: parse error near `&&'

Tags: c

I'm trying to run a simple C Program - Hello World on VSC on my mac.
It throws up this error everytime on the output screen, please understand that I'm new to coding and well uh that's that.

Here's the screenshot :
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgIBW.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    printf("%s", "Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Output : zsh: parse error near `&&'

Comment: You named your file `#include <stdio.h>.c`. You should instead name it something like `hello.c`

Comment: @thatotherguy: Even so, the IDE should not break. It ought to be passing a quoted file name to `zsh` and forming commands that do not have parse errors.

Comment: Your compilation command line seems messed up.  You're using the include line from the source code as a command line argument, which doesn't seem to be what you want.  The errors are the result of your command-line arguments not being properly quoted.  If your source file is named `myfile.c`, then you want `gcc myfile.c -o myfile`.

Comment: Your code looks good.  However, you named your file #include <stdio.h>.c.  Now, there are a couple of reserved characters there, so you should change the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your source code itself is correct. Assuming that is the **only** source code in your current project, The problem either lies with your non-portable filename, or with a misconfigured or corrupted compiler. Change your filename to something that *describes* the contained source code. A filename like `#include <stdio.h>` doesn't just make debugging difficult, but is not even allowed in some operating systems. While it does appear to be technically supported in your implementation, it could still be causing zsh to behave improperly.

Comment: `zsh` is the command-line interpreter (shell), not the compiler. And it is likely the IDE software that is at fault.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Ah I see, I misunderstood the screenshot.

Comment: No, Adam is pretty spot on with this answer. Although you are correct Eric about "the IDE *should* respect the filename" - it clearly doesn't, given the output we're seeing from the console in the screenshot.